# discussing the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

i want to prove the divergence of the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{(n+1)^p}$  it's an alternating series so we will be dealing with the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A_n x^n}{(n+1)^p}$ i tries using leibnitz test but can only prove weather it converges or not 
so is it possible to compare it to the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^p}$  as $\frac{x^n}{(n+1)^p}>\frac{1}{(n+1)^p}$  then it diverges ?

Comment: Topic:  Cauchy-Hadamard Radius (of convergence) Formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{(n+1)^p}$$

by ratio test

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^{n+1}}{(n+2)^p}\frac{(n+1)^p}{(-1)^n x^n}\right|=|x|
\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^p\to |x|$$

thus the series

- converges for $|x|<1$
- converges for $x=1$ by [Leibniz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)
- for $x=-1$ by limit comparison test converges for $p>1$ and diverges otherwise

Comment: Note that Leibniz only helps us for $x=1$, but for $x=-1$ we know the answer from the comparison test.

Comment: @Jason Yes of course you're absolutely right! Thanks for pointing it out